# Redmine 2.6.1 See Project in tree view

Tags: plugins, treeview, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am looking for a way to get redmine to show the projects list as a tree view.

I have looked a lot in internet and so far have found two plugins that should do it but none of them work.

The first on was: redmine_projects_accordion (https://github.com/reubenmallaby/redmine_projects_accordion) and the other was: Projects_Tree_View (http://www.redmine.org/plugins/projectstreeview).

I am using redmine 2.6.1

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why the down vote? did i do something wrong?

Comment: Because such questions are not related to programming: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You're asking for a link to a program that will be obsolete in some time (and already is actually).

Comment: I ré-upvote, because I do not agree with @Matthieu answer. Obsolete? Which program are you talking about? Redmine? Redmine is not "obsolete", a lot of thousands companies use it daily on a mass-production context, and it is still updated regularly as per 2018. I think this is a legitimate question here. Programming questions? No. StackOverflow is the generalist platform of StackExchange, so it is focused on "practical questions", as explained on your own link, not "programming questions".

Comment: @cedbeu Redmine will *never* be obsolete ;) (I hope not!) I was talking about the plugins (more than 6 years without updates: they're not up to the latest versions of Redmine).
This question is asking for *where* to find a software (Redmine plugin) not *how* to program one. That's why (I think) it was downvoted.

Comment: @cedbeu the point you raise actually is the reason I'm not active anymore on this site: too many "white knights" :(

Comment: @Matthieu Ah, ok, fair enough. Mmmh, in my understanding, question was not about _where_ to find those plugins, but more, "how could I achieve similar things than with those plugins, which I cannot find anymore". Redmine is cute and solid software (except it has been developed in Ruby, but, nothing is perfect… ;) ), but, it is true that it's a big weakness with its plugin system and it is sometimes a frustrating piece of software to administrate. Core system is totally not out-of-date, but most plugins are, and doc is, too… Difficult to find up-to-date doc for it. Mais bon, c'est la vie...

Comment: @Matthieu what do you mean with "White Knights"? Hope I am not an example of the people who made you left ^^ I don't feel like a white knight, most of the time… am just trying to be objective. And… Am not much active here too, I just sometimes throw a comment on a thread of interest...

Comment: @cedbeu agreed with Ruby ;) <offtopic>"White knights" are people downvoting just because they can, while we're just looking for/trying to help. Discouraging good wills is definitely not something I want to be part of</offtopic>

Comment: @Matthieu héhé, ok, we found a common ground there, then… I agree with that too… I really rarely downvoted a question. If I am not interested, I just pass my way, most of the time. Except if it's _really_ off-topic or irrelevant. Problem also is that, nowadays, there is too many "stack-exchange" platforms, and it's sometimes difficult to find our way. To be honest, I regret the time when there was *just* Stack Overflow. But well, am starting to be off-topic again, this is more a question for "Meta" ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is looking also for a solution to this I found one! There is a project call  Redmine Projects Treeview. Here you can download a plugin that does work with version 2.6.1.

Here is the link:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectstreeview/

Thanks to the CSS Ninja here is an explanition on how this works:

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

Here is also the Project website:

http://projectstreeview.sourceforge.net/

In order to make it work download the files from here: http://sourceforge.net/p/projectstreeview/code/HEAD/tree/ extract the folder projectstreeview-code-81-trunk from the zip files and rename it to "projects_treeview" and put it in the plugin folder of redmine. Restart Redmine and it should work.

Hope this helps someone else....

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't help much, but, I appreciate the effort.